# The Act of Committing

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for the act of committing? For example, `The _ murder is a crime.`. Sometimes we programmers say "commit" as in committing code to a version-control database, but that sounds for normal usage somewhat geeky (or wrong).

Answer (score 2):

***Commission*** is the act of committing.

But you would say

> The commission *of* murder is a crime.